# jQuery Mobile more buttons for one function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I use an external header for a Multi-Page Template JQM 1.4

```
$('#pageprostoriheader').load('header.html', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
});

$('#pagetestheader').load('header.html', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
});
```

In the header I have a button with ID `gumbiskanje`, that opens a popup dialog.

```
$(document).on('click', '#gumbiskanje', function(e){
  var niz = $('#niziskanje').val();
  prikaziiskanje(niz);
  window.location.href = "#pageiskanje";
});
```

when i had only one page worked all fine, but now that i have multiple page. It only works on the first page in html, but on other pages it doesn't start the dialog.

Comment: i think it is a popup ..

<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">

Comment: is it external as well? if not, do you have the same popup in each page?

Comment: Are you sure you have the necessary HTML/CSS on your other pages?

Comment: I think I have all the files ... couse everything works ok

            
I call it with

$('#pageprostoriheader').load('header.html', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
});

And all the pages are in the same HTML file ... multipage Template ..
only header.html is external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Popup div should be either place *internally* as a child of *page div*, or *externally* outside *page div*.

If placed *externally*, you need to call the below function in order to enhance/create it. Then you will be able to call it from any page.

```
$(function () {
  $("[data-role=popup]").popup();
});
```

To call it

```
$(document).on("click", "#gumbiskanje", function () {
  $("#popupLogin").popup("open");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eQTTL/)**

---

If you have the same *popup* in each page with the same *id*, you need to call it from within the active page too.

```
$(document).on("click", "#gumbiskanje", function () {
  var active = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
  $(active).find("#popupLogin").popup("open");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/P8gD8/)**

Comment: It doesnt work for me :(   at least when i tried ... it works only on the first subpage in the html file ... for others it doesnt run ... :(

Comment: @LitBe do you have the same popup in each page? please provide more details.

Comment: yes the same popup gets inserted in every header with the help of 
$('#pagetestheader').load('header.html', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").enhanceWithin();
});

is the same popup, same id ... everything ...   but it only executes  when clicked on the button in the first subpage in the html file ... 

if you need any other info just ask @Omar

Comment: @LitBe you cant place _popup_ inside a header div. It should go under pag div directly. page div should be the direct parent of any popup.

Comment: First I tried to put in the header just the a href to the popup... but it didn't work... when i puted the whole script it worked ...

I use the same popup form like on this page ... http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup/

if you know how  to do it that I put just the button for the popup in the header ... and it will work ... i would appreciate your help..

I put some code in jsfiddle if it helps http://jsfiddle.net/LitBe/jA5bQ/

Comment: please edit your question with more details in order to be able to assist you. @LitBe

Comment: did you saw the jsfiddle I added in comment ?

Comment: If I understand you right ... in the header I need to place a just a button ... that then calls a popupDIV that is somewhere in the html file ... ?

Comment: @litBe exactly, add button in header and popup outside header as explained in my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to do it ... it works on ipad2 and optimus4 but in firefox or chrome on pc no :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45940/discussion-between-omar-and-litbe)